# django running error: self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size]) 'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())

Tags: django, datetime

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
>    self.finish_response()
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
>    self.finish_response()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
>    self.write(data)
>    self.finish_response()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 210, in write
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
>    self.write(data)
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 210, in write
>    self.send_headers()
>    self.write(data)
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 210, in write
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
>    self.send_preamble()
>    self.send_headers()
>    self.finish_response()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
>    self.send_preamble()
>    self.send_headers()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
>[27/Aug/2012 10:30:06] "GET /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6309
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
>    self.write(data)
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 210, in write
>    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
>    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
>    self.send_preamble()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
>    self.send_headers()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
>    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
>    self.send_preamble()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
>   self.flush()
>    self.flush()
>    self.flush()
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
>    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
>    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
>    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
>    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
>error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: I run my django programe, and sometimes,  when i send a request, the programe go down , and above is the Traceback, this problem has troubled me a lot, who know what is the matter?

Comment: what you have tried which program u had run could you please the program snippet please ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your urls.py file. When I had this problem come up, it was due to the bold part of this line of code:

```
url((r'^foo/(?P<thing1>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+),**(?P<thing2>%s**' % REGEX), 'views.foo'),
```

Note the lack of a closing paren. This apparently caused the entire thing to go haywire, spitting the same kind of errors you got here. So check for missing parens and bad regex syntax--my bet is that one of those is the root of your problem.